# jsconfig.json Problem in a Package Dependency

Tags: package, unlocked-package, cli, sfdx-error

I have been trying to build (force:package:version:create) a package `first-project` which depends on an other package `other-project` of mine.
I got the following error:

`Unexpected file found in package directory: C:\...\other-project-dir\force-app\main\default\lwc\jsconfig.json`

Both projects were created in VS Code with command SFDX: Create Project. In particular, both projects have the `**/.eslintrc.json` and `**/jsconfig.json` entries in the .forceignore file (also, in both projects the lwc/ folders contain no other files apart from the two config files.) When removing the two config files from the lwc/ folder of `other-project` the problem goes away.

**Questions**

1. I suspect this to be a bug. If so, should I create an issue (and how / where)?
2. This is the first time I build a project with a dependency; is my sfdx-project.json (see below) as it should?

VS Code version info:

```
Commit: 3866c3553be8b268c8a7f8c0482c0c0177aa8bfa
Date: 2021-08-19T11:56:46.957Z
Electron: 13.1.7
Chrome: 91.0.4472.124
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.36-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

CLI version:

`sfdx-cli/7.113.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.4`

first-project\sfdx-project.json:

```
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "first-project",
            "versionName": "Version 1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "other-project",
                    "versionNumber": "1.0.1.LATEST"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "../other-project/force-app",
            "default": false,
            "package": "other-project",
            "versionName": "Version 1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.1.NEXT"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "52.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "first-project": "0Ho09000000CaklCAC",
        "other-project": "0Ho090000010wCsCAI",
        "first-project@1.0.0-1": "04t09000000uzO4AAI",
    }
}
```